# Changing action href

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form that should change action href based on checkbox. One action is contact.html and the other is link to external page responsible for subscribtions (freshmail). For example https://stackoverflow.com. If I change action to https://stackoverflow.com the form doesn't send messages to my email, but only goes to https://stackoverflow.com
How can I change it to send emails always, but enroll to freshmail only when checkbox is checked?

```
$('#site.contact #left :checkbox').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
  console.log('checked');
  $('.jsForm').attr('action', 'https://app.freshmail.com/pl/actions/subscribe/');
} else {
  $('.jsForm').attr('action', 'kontakt.html');
  console.log('unchecked');
}
```

Code above changes action perfectly, but what next?

Comment: enroll on your server

Comment: If I could I wouldn't ask

Comment: The answer is to use CURL or similar on the server. You have not told us the server language. You read the checked status at the server and act acccordingly. You cannot have one form do two actions unless you ajax to your server and THEN submit to the subscription

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#idcheck').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
  alert("ola");
  console.log('checked');
  $('.jsForm').prop('action', 'https://app.freshmail.com/pl/actions/subscribe/');
} else {
  $('.jsForm').prop('action', 'kontakt.html');
  console.log('unchecked');
}

});
```

Try prop instead of attr and close change(function() { code });

Comment: I wrote, that changing action works. I want to do 2 actions if checkbox is checked. One is external link and the other is contact.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  $('#jsForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    if ($("#subscribe").is(":checked")) {
      e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
      $(this).prop('action', 'https://app.freshmail.com/pl/actions/subscribe/');
      $.get("kontakt.html",function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data); // success
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#jsForm').submit(); // note: there can be nothing name="submit" in the form
        },2000); // give them a chance to read
      });
    });
  }
});
```

using

```
<form id="jsform" action="kontakt.html">
  <input type="checkbox id="subscribe" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```